# Is there any macroscopic experiment that reproduces the results of Stern-Gerlach experiments on electron spin?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin

In a Stern-Gerlach experiment measuring electron spin, electrons are diverted to one of two areas on a detector, rather than ending up in a continuum between those two areas. I'm wondering if there is any macroscopic/classical situation that has a similar result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by macroscopic? The experiment was first done with silver atoms which, due to having 1 unpaired electron of spin 1/2, split into 2 distinct beams. This was a quantum mechanical event that was visible macroscopically.

If by macroscopic you mean on a large object instead of a beam of atoms then I don't think it would be feasible or possible to do this same type of experiment.

As far as classical goes, definitely no. Spin is a purely quantum mechanical phenomenon with no classical counterpart.

Comment: By macroscopic, I mean for objects that have a more "normal" magnetic moment caused by motion of an electrical field - which is somewhat of a classical counterpart to spin (tho i understand they're not the same).

Answer (score 0):

"The Barnett effect is the magnetization of an uncharged body when spun on its axis. It was discovered by American physicist Samuel Barnett in 1915... The magnetization occurs parallel to the axis of spin. Barnett was motivated by a prediction by Owen Richardson in 1908, later named the Einstein–de Haas effect, that magnetizing a ferromagnet can induce a mechanical rotation. He instead looked for the opposite effect, that is, that spinning a ferromagnet could change its magnetization." Cited from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnett_effect).

Einstein and other scientists wanted to find out more about the proposed from Faraday molecular currents, which should be responsible for magnetic dipole. What was found by the help of him, de Haas, Barnett, Stern, Gerlach and others was the confirmation that electrons rotate around their axis and that corresponding to this they have a magnetic dipole moment. More information you get in [this paper](http://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/411c/EinsteindeHaas.pdf).